# Spring properties: spring.config.additional-location not verriden property values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

I'm using this command line in order to start my service locally:

```
mvn -pl rep-digital-api clean compile spring-boot:run \
  -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.additional-location=front-pre-props.properties
```

`pre` profile is activated since `front-pre-props.properties` contains `spring.profiles.active=pre`.

Into default `application-dev.properties` I've set this property:

```
api.path-web=web
```

Nevertheless, I need to simulate `pre` profile into my local environment. So I need to change this property value:

```
 api.path-web=other-path
```

Nevertheless, this property is not overriden.

Also I've tested it seting `-Dapi.path-web=other-value` in to mvn command, but it doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your file front-pre-props.properties located? If its in classpath, that is, under resources, then you don't need to define the spring.config.additional-location. By default spring-boot picks up these locations : DEFAULT_SEARCH_LOCATIONS = "classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/";

Comment: It's into my filesystemm outside of my project.

Comment: In your case then you need to specify the locations as:
file:./absolutepath/front-pre-props.properties

Comment: Could you provide any more helping code, please? I mean, how do I specify this value?

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a file from the file system, you need to set the value of property `spring.config.additional-location` to `file:/pathtofile/yourfile.properties`.

Lets say your file `front-pre-props.properties` is in path `/Users/demo/front-pre-props.properties`

Then you can execute the run command as  :

```
mvn -pl rep-digital-api -Dspring.config.additional-location=“file:/Users/demo/front-pre-props.properties” clean compile
spring-boot:run
```